# Hugo page/subsection under a different domain

Tags: hugo

I am planning a Hugo site accessible under example.com and I'd like example.com/foobar to be accessible as foobar.com. Even better would be example.com/foobar/baz to be accessible as foobar.com/baz. I read https://gohugo.io/content-management/organization/ but I am not clear whether this is supported.

Comment: There is a lot of information you may want to include in your question. Will the site use the same exact layout as `example.com` in `foobar.com`? Are these two different sites or one site stand alone with a path as a sub path? Two diff sites and content using the same exact assets (theme)? Too many assumptions to be made to answer it fully, but I will answer it with my assumptions.

Comment: I thought it was clear: there's one site. A page of it (or -- better -- a subsection of it) is accessible under a different domain. Basically, `s#example.com/foobar#foobar.com#` for all URLs containing `/foobar`.

Comment: If my assumptions are correct in my answer, you could set it up the way I said to have the least amount of issues. Hugo will allow for other configurations also, but they are more complicated than that setup.

Answer (score 0):

**Hugo** is powerful enough to handle what you want, but not sure how you will be setting up the content, so we will have to make some assumptions.

### Assumptions

- The content for `example.com` `foobar.com` will be in their own location.
- They will both be using the same theme
- These 2 sites will have their own assets (duplicated) and not know the other site exists other than linking to their domain paths.

### Setup

This is possible with Hugo and will take 2 build commands to accomplish.

Setup 2 content locations:

`example.com` - `example-content`

`foobar.com` - `foobar-content`

Build them using 2 commands:

`example.com` - `hugo --contentDir example-content --destination public`

`foobar.com` - `hugo --contentDir foobar-content --destination public/foobar`

**NOTE:** The commands for the server locally could be used also to target the content.  You would need to make sure to setup the paths correctly in the theme, so you are using relative paths from the root published folder location. Any themes or layouts will be used by either site.

Comment: The content for example.com foobar.com will be in their own location. -- but I wanted the *same* content to be accessible under different domains. One site. Two domains. The second domain points to a directory.

Comment: Sure, but you need to consider where the second domain is going to get it's assets. These concerns have nothing to do with Hugo as much as how the layout of your structured requirements are setup.